# LaTeX - Reference Help

Tags: cross-referencing

I have some problems, when I try to use the command `\ref{}`.

When I compile my LaTeX code, It will not show me any number at all in the final pdf-document eventhough that I am using the correct command `\ref{fig:statestik}`.

I have my picture:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{../../../Billeder/Horeskader/statestik.jpg}
\caption{This is my caption.}
\label{fig:statestik}
\end{figure}
```

I should just say, that i'm writing in subiles, and load it all in a main file.

Comment: What does "will not work" means?? Did you run `pdflatex` twice?

Comment: Yes I have tryed to run pdflatex twice.

What does "will not work" means?? - It means that, when i compile my pdflatex it will not show the ref.

I have some text thet I want to ref to a figure, but eather it show nothing or ?? in the pdflatex

Comment: And what does "will not work" mean? Do you get any errors, or any warnings? You need to be a bit more specific.

Comment: No I get no error, and that is what i dont understand.

Comment: I can see I get an LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:statestik' on page 4 undefined on input line

Comment: Please make a _complete_ small document that shows the problem and add it (or them) to the question. It is hard to debug code that we can't see.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please add a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 0):

run this example twice and everything will be fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}    
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{../../../Billeder/Horeskader/statestik.jpg}
\caption{This is my caption.}
\label{fig:statestik}
\end{figure}

Figure~\ref{fig:statestik} is a nice figure

\end{document}
```

Comment: He said that he did this so I don't think that will fix his problem.